# Rails Pow access request.subdomain in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using POW to run Rails locally on my MAC.  So, my url has a subdomain.

I'd like to use the subdomain in a model, but the following code gives me "undefined local variable or method `request'".

Code:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_tenant(:tenant)

ct = Tenant.where(subdomain: request.subdomain).first
if ct.data.present?
  ct.data.each do |key, value|
    ransacker key do |parent|
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:data], key)
    end
  end
end
```

PS - that code works fine in a view.

I'm trying this because I want to Ransack search on user defined fields in an hstore type field.  I first tried using `if ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.data.present?` - That works great locally, but not on Heroku (I haven't been able to figure out why).

UPDATE1

I tried putting this in the applications.rb:

```
helper_method :my_var

def my_var
  @ct = Tenant.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomains.first)
end
```

Then in the model:

```
if @ct.data.present?
```

But, @ct is nil.  How do you set a variable in the applications controller to be used in a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)

  ct = Tenant.find(self.first.tenant)
  if ct.data.present?
    ct.data.each do |key, value|
      ransacker key do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:data], key)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Model classes have no understanding of a request (as they shouldn't, seeing as they are representations of a collection of attributes in a database). If you really need to set something based on the subdomain in the model, I'd suggest creating a method that would take a request argument.

It's not exactly clear what you're doing, but from the code you provided, you could do something to the effect of:

```
# app/models/vehicle.rb
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)

  def self.ct=(request)
    @ct = Tenant.where(subdomain: request.subdomain).first
  end
end
```

Comment: Strange example you define instance variable in singleton class method.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I tried adding your def, then this `  if @ct.data.present?`. But, @ct is nil. See my updated question.